# How do you send div's content as email with PHP while preserving the html format?

Tags: php, html

Let's imagine this simple, I have a div (myDiv) inside a form which includes this content:

```
<div id=myDiv>Hi Same, please click <a href="http://www.test.com">Click here</a></div>
```

Now I need a php script that will send this div to someones email exactly keeping the proper html format like this:

Hi Same, Please click [Click here](http://www.test.com)

The problem is when I have this content in a textbox it sends it all as text. I need to send the div content.

Comment: Thank you. I just did! i'm using free service from http://formtoemail.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using free service of formtoemail.com, you should have file you downloaded from their website. Find this line there:

```
mail($my_email,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

and add right before it

```
$headers .= PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html;";
```

so finaly you will have:

```
$headers .= PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html;";
mail($my_email,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: This comment was a saver! Thanks a lot. I will give it a try and will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Hi, is there any possibility you could also have a look at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838677/how-to-grab-input-email-address-and-use-it-in-formtoemail-php-script It is related issue I am facing. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the email with a `content-type=text/html` header.

This tells the email client to render the email as HTML.

Exactly how you do that depends on if you are using the built in php functions or a library such as swiftmailer or phpmailer.

Comment: Thanks Alien. I will give it a go and will let you know the results.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), if you use this method:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

The message will be send as HTML, so it should work.