# How to grab input email address and use it in FormToEmail.php script?

Tags: php, html, email

I am using FormToEmail.php free script to send some form data from a page where user enters their email and recipient's email and obviously some text as message.

In FormToEmail.php there is a place where I insert the email which I would like the content to be submitted.

I need to set the email which is entered as "recipient's" email dynamically in FormToEmail.php file so that the content will get emailed to recipient's email. How do I do that?

Comment: Here is the link to download the script http://formtoemail.com/FormToEmail.zip

Comment: Just imaging I have a page, that has 3 fields, Sender Email, recipient Email, and Message. in FormToEmail.php there is a place where you have to actually write the email of recipient. I need to code it in a way that whatevert is typed in recipient's email gets inserted into FormToEmail.php section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a text in comments of that script:

```
Step 2:

Enter your email address.
```

After comments block there is a line:

```
$my_email = "delete these words and put the email address only in here between the quotes";
```

Suppose you have harcoded address instead of "delete these ....". You should simply replace that line with:

```
$my_email = !empty($_REQUEST['recepient_email_field_name']) ? $_REQUEST['recepient_email_field_name'] : "default email address";
```

Where `recepient_email_field_name` is name of a field on a form where user should enter his email and default email address should be replaced with that email you have there currently.

Comment: Thank you, I'm just going to test it and let you know the results.

Comment: Excellent! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code:

```
$my_email = "delete these words and put the email address only in here between the quotes";
```

Add this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
  $my_email = trim($_POST['email']);
} else {
  $my_email = "defaultemailaddress@domain.com";
}
```

Replace the default with your own or any other.